# Is it possible to get the whole source XML as CDTA in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to get this in XSLT. Is this possible?

Source XML

```
<Parent>
   <Child></Child>
   <Child></Child>
   <Child></Child>
   <Child></Child>
</Parent>
```

Output XML

```
<Issue>
  <Node1>Something happening here</Node1>
   <Node2>Something happening here</Node2>
<Node3><![CDATA[
<Parent>
       <Child></Child>
       <Child></Child>
       <Child></Child>
       <Child></Child>
    </Parent>
]]>
</Issue>
```

I want the whole input xml as CDATA of `<Node3>`

Is this possible?

My XSLT looks like below (Snippet)

```
    <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:call-template name="Issue"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Issue">
      <xsl:call-template name="Node1"/> 
      <xsl:call-template name="Node2"/> 
      <xsl:call-template name="Node3"/> 
    </xsl:template>
    ....
   <xsl:template name="Node3">
   <!-- Here as CDATA i want the input xml content-->
    </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone help me solve this? I am using XSLT 1.0

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using? In XSLT 2.0 you can use `cdata-section-elements="Node3"`, but you mentioned that you are using 1.0. In that case I think you're stuck with processor-specific extensions.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, you could try this dirty technique (not guaranteed to work):

```
<xsl:template name="Node3">
  <Node3>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy-of select="/" />
    <xsl:text>]]></xsl:text>
  </Node3>
</xsl:template>
```

I say "dirty" because `disable-output-escaping` usually means you're trying to use a hammer to drive a screw; i.e. you're using a tool for a purpose it wasn't designed to serve. It's not guaranteed to work, especially if the XSLT processor doesn't have control over serialization.

You might be able to avoid this dirty technique. I would start by asking, **why** should the output XML be in a CDATA section? There is almost certainly a different requirement behind the CDATA requirement (otherwise the CDATA requirement is arbitrary).

Maybe the real requirement is that you want the input XML to be escaped in the output, so that whatever XML parser reads it next will read it as text instead of parsing it into a tree?

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364884/423105

Comment: Thanks. Actually this worked   `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
               <xsl:copy-of select="/" />
             <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>`

Comment: for historical reasons, I need to save the input xml and store in db

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction regarding `<`. Will edit my answer. I don't see a need for d-o-e or `&gt;` on the second `xsl:text`, since `>` doesn't need to be escaped. But then I haven't tested it either.

Comment: Ok, I guess a serializer could legally escape `>` as `&gt;` even though it doesn't have to. And d-o-e would (often) prevent that.